# publish on friends wall but after obtaining their permission

Tags: php, jquery, facebook

I'm writing Facebook application using PHP SDK and I can from this app publish messages on friends' walls.

Is it possible to force it so that I can publish the messages on their walls only if they accepted that? For example for the first time I try to publish something on my friends wall from my app they are asked if app can do it.

EDIT1:

To make it more clear:

Now user uses application accepts permissions and so on. In that application user can choose friends and write message. After that this message is posted on their walls (in behalf of this user who uses app) (they dont have to accept any permissions). I would like to be able to post this information on their wall only if they accept any permission for that.

Answer (score 0):

There is actually no way of doing what you mentioned. Users can post on their friends walls without requiring permission from the user. Facebook doesn't give the user an option of accepting this. You can block a user from posting, but if u allow, you cannot rep-approve any post. 
You can delete the post later alright and i think even change the privacy.

Now, you could develop your own wall as a canvas app and allow users to post on this wall and give necessary priviledges, but I don't think that's what you are looking for.

Explain the question a little more, an provide some code so we can give a better insight. 
As for whether you can publish on people's walls without them granting access to your app?
No you can't. The user has to approve the app before it can access any non-public data.

Once you get this permission you can use it to post on his wall

```
  $args = array(
  'message'   => 'Hello from my App!',
  'link'      => 'http://www.masteringapi.com/',
  'caption'   => 'Visit MasteringAPI.com For Facebook API Tutorials!'
  );
  $post_id = $facebook->api("/me/feed", "post", $args);
```

Comment: I still dont get it. Let's define the two users:
poster: person who is using your app
Friend: the friend of the poster on who's app its being posted
so you want the poster's message to be published if and only if the friend accepts?

Comment: see my edit. You can't do what you are asking because FB doesn't allow you moderate posts that way